# Problems setting up debugging in Visual Studio code for Chrome, have it working for Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, firefox, vuejs3

I have the following in **.vscode/launch.json** :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  {
    "type": "firefox",
    "request": "launch",
    "reAttach": true,
    "name": "vuejs: firefox",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    "firefoxExecutable": "C:/Users/Geoffrey Swenson/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe",
    "breakOnLoad": true,
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
      "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/*": "*",
      "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
    },
   "preLaunchTask": "serve"
  },
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "reAttach": true,
    "name": "vuejs: chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    "breakOnLoad": true,
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
      "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/*": "*",
      "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
    },
    "preLaunchTask": "serve"
  }]
}
```

I have the following in **.vscode/tasks.json** :

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "start",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "serve",
      "isBackground": true
    },
    {
      "label": "serve",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "serve",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": [{
        "base": "$tsc-watch",
        "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": "Starting development server",
            "endsPattern": "Compiled successfully"
        }
      }],
      "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have **vue.config.ts** :

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

Breakpoints work in Firefox, though I have to press F5 the first time I load it. They never work in Chrome. Firefox involves installing a debugger extension, but there is supposedly no need for this for Chrome.

Comment: I have also tried adding debugging to chrome in the registry using a command line switch, but it has no effect.

Comment: Edge, which is also webkit requires an extension, but it still doesn't work so well, but at least better than chrome. Any page with a breakpoint breaks at the stop of execution, which is barely useful.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set launch.json and then set your config file as you need:

hereafter an example which works with vite running as bundler in front and server in back

```
{
"debug": {
    "javascript": {
        "terminalOptions": {
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "trace": true
        }
    }
},
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Run bundler",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "command": "npm run <your-command-to-run-app>",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

}

Then forget webpack and use vite, thus you need to install vite and  a vite config file

```
 import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
 import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
 // cf. https://vitejs.dev/config/
 export default defineConfig(async ({ command, mode }) => {
 return {
    plugins: [vue()],
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3080',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 3080,
        strictPort: true
    },
    build: {
        outDir: './server/public'
    }
 };
 });
```

I use typescript and in my ts.config.json, I setted

```
 ...
 "sourceMap": true,
 "types": ["vite/server"],
 "skipLibCheck": true,
 "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
 ...
```

hope that's will help folk's !

Comment: Where do you define "run front" ?

Comment: There is something not-complete about this answer, it doesn't work. I'm all for using vite, but I don't understand this answer, it doesn't work.

Comment: "run front" is the command for node when you run npm => ex: "npm run front". but I removed it, for clearance

Comment: We have to support IE11 so I'm going to have to probably not use vite